# Dojo - dijit/ComboBox - mouse selection not working

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

Not sure if this is a bug with ComboBox or an error with my implementation. I'm filling the ComboBox with values from an array. The ComboBox seems to mostly work - all the values are there, the default value is being set, suggestions are coming up. The only problem is that I can't select any of the dropdown options by clicking them with my mouse. I can only select options by using the arrows buttons + Enter. Is this by design or a bug?

Here's an excerpt of my HTML, for a templated widget:

```
<td style="width:25%;"><input data-dojo-attach-point="testReports" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"></input></td>
```

Here's my JavaScript code. I populate the ComboBox, then place it into the HTML template:

```
var reportStore = new Memory();
for(i = 0; i < this.parent.reportNames.length; i++){
    var reportObject = {};
    reportObject.id = i;
    reportObject.name = this.parent.reportNames[i];
    reportStore.put(reportObject);
}
this.testReports.set("id", "reportsDropDown");
this.testReports.set("name", "reports");
this.testReports.set("value", this.parent.reportNames[0]);
this.testReports.set("store", reportStore);
this.testReports.set("searchAttr", "name");
```

Is there anything else I should consider to get the mouse selection to work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `onchange` event to your input tag? This should pick up and select list changes made using the mouse.

```
<input data-dojo-attach-point="testReports" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox" onchange="processComboChange(this)"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried defining the plugin a different way and it seems to be working now:

HTML:

```
<td style="width:25%;"><input data-dojo-attach-point="testReports"></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
var reportStore = new Memory();

for(i = 0; i < this.parent.reportNames.length; i++){
    var reportObject = {};
    reportObject.id = i;
    reportObject.name = this.parent.reportNames[i];
    reportStore.put(reportObject);
}

var comboBox= new ComboBox({
    id: "reportsDropDown",
    name: "reports",
    value: this.parent.reportNames[0],
    store: reportStore,
    searchAttr: "name"
}, this.testReports).startup();
```

I'm figuring that the other way I tried was messing with the order that things need to be loaded. Not sure if anyone else can explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly caused your problem, but looks like it's because you mixed programmatic and declarative methods of creating widget. Dojo is very sensitive to such things and you can spend hours, trying to figure out why your widet doesn't work...
There are couple things I'd like to mention regarding your code. If you create your widget declaratively you can pass necessary properties inline, without setting them in your js. So instead of `this.testReports.set("id", "reportsDropDown");`
you can make it in following way:

```
  <input data-dojo-attach-point="testReports" 
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboBox"
        data-dojo-props="store: store, searchAttr: name">
  </input>
```

or if you prefer programmatic creation:

*template*

```
<input id="test-reports"></input>
```

*js*

```
var testReports = new ComboBox({
        id: "testReports",
        name: "reports",
        value: "",
        store: store,
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "test-reports").startup();
```

And in second case you don't have to define `data-dojo-attach-point` attribute for an element, and use element id instead of referencing `this.someNode`